# how to shorten the distance between the border and text in Textfield in material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[My UI look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUjEO.png)

I am doing my Reactjs project and dueling with the material ui Textfield.
I used

```
const styles = theme => ({
    input: {
        width: 30,
        height:30,
        marginTop:10,
        fontSize:7,
        padding:0,
    },
})
```

to style my Textfield which code is

```
<span>Size &nbsp;</span>
<span style={{marginTop:'10px'}}>
  <TextField 
      InputProps={{
          className: classes.input
      }} 
      variant="outlined" />
</span>
```

But because the size of my textfield is small, my text can be shown within the border. I think the reason is that the distance between the border and text is too large. Is there any way to shorten the distance? Or any solution to help me show the text in my textfield.I tried padding, but it does not work.

Any answer would be appreciated. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The InputProps className prop is targeting the wrapper of the input if you want to modify the padding of the actual input, do this

```
inputWrapper: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    marginTop: 10,
    fontSize: 7,
    "& input": {
      padding: 0
    }
  }

<TextField 
      InputProps={{
          className: classes.inputWrapper
      }} 
      variant="outlined" />
```